# django crispy forms file upload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm having trouble getting an image field to upload correctly with django crispy forms. Everything else on the form and page works fine, but the image field does not error or save, it just passes right over it. I am able to add the image through admin just fine, it only fails on my crispy form.

```
#views.py
@login_required
def dashboard(request, **kwargs):
    '''
    perform managerial and administrative tasks for a blog. Only
    available to the blog owner
    '''
    alert_message = ""
    status = ""

    blog_slug = kwargs['blog']
    blog = get_object_or_404(PersonalBlog, slug=blog_slug)

    # handle the form submit to update blog data
    form = BlogEditForm(instance=blog)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if blog.owner == request.user:
            form = BlogEditForm(request.POST, instance=blog)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                alert_message = "Your blog data has been updated successfully"
                status = "saved"
            else:
                alert_message = "There was a problem saving the data you entered. Please correct the errors above."
                status = "error"
        else:
            alert_message = "You do not have access to update this blog's information."
            status = "error"


    return render(request, "blogcontent/dashboard.html", {'alert_message':alert_message,
                                                          'status':status, 'form':form})


#forms.py
class BlogEditForm(ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea())
    twitter = forms.CharField(required=False, help_text="show twitter feed, and allow people to interact with you on twitter")
    twitter_widget_id = forms.CharField(required=False, help_text="required to show a timeline widget for your twitter account. " + \
                                                  "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></span>")
    instagram = forms.CharField(required=False, help_text="show instagram feed on your blog page")
    disqus = forms.CharField(required=False, help_text="allow comments at the bottom of your blog posts")

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalBlog

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                '<h2 class="text-center">Edit data about your blog</h2>',
                Field('owner', type="hidden"),
                Field('title', type="hidden"),
                Div('description', css_class="col-md-12"),
                Div('twitter', css_class="col-md-6"),
                Div('twitter_widget_id', css_class="col-md-6"),
                Div('instagram', css_class="col-md-6"),
                Div('disqus', css_class="col-md-6"),
                Div('logo', css_class="col-md-12"),
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Update Info', css_class='btn-lg'),
                css_class="text-center"
            ),

        )

#dashboard.html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% crispy form %}
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I knew it was going to be something dumb. I was not attaching the request.FILES to the form.save() object.

```
form = BlogEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=blog)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried changing:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

To just:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form %}
```

Also in your code, your are calling:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

You don't want to `save()` the form.  You want to save the form data to a model instance.  So `create()` a model using the form data.  This may be why as well. `Forms` are just used to hold data until you clean it and save it to the database using a `model`.

Comment: I just tried taking off the form tag and it has the same result, with the same generated HTML. 

This example is actually just to modify an instance, there is different logic when creating the model instance (which isn't on this question), which behaves the same way with the logo field.